# Change password script with BCRYPT

Tags: php

I have login/register form which are working perfectly. Now I'm trying to make script to allow user to change password but I can't understand why doesn't work. This is the HTML form

```
<form action="editAccount.php" method="post"> 
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Password:</span>
      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary custom-button btn-block" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save Changes</button>                           
    <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon">Confirm password:</span>
          <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password">
    </div>                                                                                                            
</form>
```

And this is the PHP part

```
if(empty($_SESSION['id'])) 
{ 
    header("Location: userAction.php"); 
    die("Redirecting to userAction.php"); 
} 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//basic validation
if(strlen($_POST['password']) < 3){
    $error[] = 'Password is too short.';
}

if(strlen($_POST['passwordConfirm']) < 3){
    $error[] = 'Confirm Password is too short.';
}

if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['passwordConfirm']){
    $error[] = 'Password and Confirm password doesn't match.';
}
  if(empty($error)){

        $hashedpassword = $user->password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        try {
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = :hashedpassword WHERE id = :user_id");
            $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':hashedpassword' => $hashedpassword,
                    ':user_id' => $_SESSION['id']
            ));

            header('Location: userAction.php?action=joined');
            exit;

        } catch(PDOException $e) 
          {
             $error[] = $e->getMessage();
          }

   }
}
```

On `var_dump($_POST['password']` result is - `string(11) "newpassword"` i.e. POST got the password.

On `var_dump($hashedpassword)` result is - `NULL`. So the problem must be in hashing function.

Here is also what I have in `$user`

```
class User extends Password{

private $_db;

function __construct($pdo){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->_db = $pdo;
}

 private function get_user_hash($username){ 

    try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
        $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        return $row['password'];

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
 }

 public function login($username,$password){

    $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);

    if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;          
        return true;
    }   
 }
 public function login_user_id($username){  

    try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

        $row = $stmt->fetch();

        return $row['id'];

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
 }

 public function logout(){
    session_destroy();
 }

 public function is_logged_in(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
        return true;
    }       
 }

}
```

Comment: In `editAccount.php` Theres a misplaced quote in this line - `'Password and Confirm password doesn't match.'`(Need to escape `'` in doesn't)

Comment: My mistake. Thank's for that. Fixed it but the other problem is still there.

Comment: What is `$user->password_hash()`? That does not seem to be in the `user` class. Is that mistakenly used instead of php's builtin function `password_hash()`?

Comment: May be is mistake.. I've used this part from login/register part. But even if I remove `$user` and leave only `$hashedpassword = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);` the script still doesn't work.

Comment: Tried ot php 5.4, 5.5 and 5.6..

Comment: Hmm.. [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) will return something even for null/empty string values.

Comment: It doesn't even enter into `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { ...` block because I've tried to submit empty form and didn't complain for empty inputs... short password or whatever.

Comment: Ah... That's coz you don't have a `<input type="submit" />` in your html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you told in comments, it doesn't even enter into the `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {` part, because you don't have an input named "submit".

Try it with an `<input type="submit" name="submit">` or a hidden input named "submit".

Comment: Uh.. why `<button>` doesn't work :) ... so this fixed the problem and now the password is changed.

Comment: @John um.. You might be able to use "name" attribute with `<button>` too. Sorry i've forgot mentioning it >.<

Comment: One last thing. In the script where the password is updated how can I logout automatically user from his account?

Comment: After executing your $stmt query, call your logout() method from your User class ( `$user->logout()` ). Or if this fails, you could just destroy the session: `session_destroy();`

Comment: Great! Thank's one more time!